# Grunt won't load the node server

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, nodemon

My `gruntfile.js` is:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            jade: {
                files: ['app/views/**'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
            js: {
                files: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'app/**/*.js', 'public/js/**', 'test/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
            html: {
                files: ['public/views/**'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                },
            },
            css: {
                files: ['public/css/**'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: {
                src: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'app/**/*.js', 'public/js/**', 'test/**/*.js'],
                options: {
                    jshintrc: true
                }
            }
        },
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    file: 'server.js',
                    args: [],
                    ignoredFiles: ['public/**'],
                    watchedExtensions: ['js'],
                    nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                    delayTime: 1,
                    env: {
                        PORT: 3000
                    },
                    cwd: __dirname
                }
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        },
        mochaTest: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                require: 'server.js'
            },
            src: ['test/mocha/**/*.js']
        },
        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            }
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'test/karma/karma.conf.js'
            }
        }
    });

    //Load NPM tasks 
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');

    //Making grunt default to force in order not to break the project.
    grunt.option('force', true);

    //Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concurrent']);

    //Test task.
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);
};
```

and when I type `grunt`, I get:

```
$ grunt
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 69 files lint free.

Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Usually it says `Express started on Port 3000`, but suddenly it isn't. Not sure what's going on. Any ideas?

When running with the `-v` flag, I get:

```
Running tasks: nodemon

    Running "nodemon" task

    Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
    Verifying property nodemon.dev exists in config...OK
    File: [no files]
    Options: file="server.js", args=[], ignoredFiles=["public/**"], watchedExtensions=["js"], nodeArgs=["--debug"], delayTime=1, env={"PORT":3000}, cwd="/Users/shamoon/Sites/blocksearcher"
    Loading "env.js" tasks...OK
    + env
    Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
    + default, test

    Running tasks: watch

    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.jade.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.js.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.html.files exists in config...OK
    Verifying property watch.css.files exists in config...OK
    Live reload server started on port: 35729


        Watching app/views for changes.
    Watching app/views/includes for changes.
    ...
```

Comment: Try running it with the `-v` flag for more information!

Comment: Added the output of `-v`

Comment: I have done the below mentioned changes but there is some new error now, is this all u have to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the changelog of grunt-nodemon: https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon#changelog.

You must have update your dependencies recently and grunt-nodemon changed a few properties.

```
- file is now script
- ignoredFiles -> ignore
- watchedFolders -> watch
- watchedExtensions -> ext
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change you options.file to script or keep both.

```
nodemon: {
    dev: {
        script: 'server.js',
        options: {
            file: 'server.js',
            args: [],
            ignoredFiles: ['public/**'],
            watchedExtensions: ['js'],
            nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
            delayTime: 1,
            env: {
                PORT: 3000
            },
            cwd: __dirname
        }
    }
}
```