# Grunt stops outputting information after starting the node debug server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, meanjs, gruntfile

My problem is similar to this: [Grunt won't load the node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234304/grunt-wont-load-the-node-server)

However, the answers do not solve the problem in my case. Here is my gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Unified Watch Object
    var watchFiles = {
        serverViews: ['app/views/**/*.*'],
        serverJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
        clientViews: ['public/modules/**/views/**/*.html'],
        clientJS: ['public/js/*.js', 'public/modules/**/*.js'],
        clientCSS: ['public/modules/**/*.css', 'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/icomoon.css'],
        mochaTests: ['app/tests/**/*.js']
    };

    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            serverViews: {
                files: watchFiles.serverViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            serverJS: {
                files: watchFiles.serverJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientViews: {
                files: watchFiles.clientViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            },
            clientJS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientCSS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientCSS,
                tasks: ['csslint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: {
                src: watchFiles.clientJS.concat(watchFiles.serverJS),
                options: {
                    jshintrc: true
                }
            }
        },
        csslint: {
            options: {
                csslintrc: '.csslintrc',
            },
            all: {
                src: watchFiles.clientCSS
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            production: {
                options: {
                    mangle: false
                },
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.min.js': 'public/dist/application.js'
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.min.css': '<%= applicationCSSFiles %>'
                }
            }
        },
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    file: 'server.js',
                    nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                    ext: 'js,html',
                    watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
                }
            }
        },
        'node-inspector': {
            custom: {
                options: {
                    'web-port': 1337,
                    'web-host': 'localhost',
                    'debug-port': 5858,
                    'save-live-edit': true,
                    'no-preload': true,
                    'stack-trace-limit': 50,
                    'hidden': []
                }
            }
        },
        ngAnnotate: {
            production: {
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.js': '<%= applicationJavaScriptFiles %>'
                }
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            default: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
            debug: ['nodemon', 'watch', 'node-inspector'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true,
                limit: 10
            }
        },
        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            },
            secure: {
                NODE_ENV: 'secure'
            }
        },
        mochaTest: {
            src: watchFiles.mochaTests,
            test: {
                options: {
                    require: 'server.js',
                    reporter: 'spec'
                }
            }
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
            }
        }
    });

    // Load NPM tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Making grunt default to force in order not to break the project.
    grunt.option('force', true);

    // A Task for loading the configuration object
    grunt.task.registerTask('loadConfig', 'Task that loads the config into a grunt option.', function() {
        var init = require('./config/init')();
        var config = require('./config/config');

        grunt.config.set('applicationJavaScriptFiles', config.assets.js);
        grunt.config.set('applicationCSSFiles', config.assets.css);
    });

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'concurrent:default']);

    // Debug task.
    grunt.registerTask('debug', ['lint', 'concurrent:debug']);

    // Secure task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('secure', ['env:secure', 'lint', 'concurrent:default']);

    // Lint task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint', 'csslint']);

    // Build task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['lint', 'loadConfig', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

    // Test tasks.
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);
    grunt.registerTask('test-front', ['env:test', 'karma:unit']);
    grunt.registerTask('test-back', ['env:test', 'mochaTest']);
};
```

When I run grunt (ignoring the lint errors), I get:

```
Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
Running "watch" task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
```

And it just stops there... Usually it would say MEANjs app has started on localhost:3000 and when I open the app in the browser, it would show the huge list of files as they are requested and loaded from through the browser.

This is the grunt -v version(too many watched files, so I deleted some for clarity and brevity):

```
Running "nodemon" task

Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Verifying property nodemon.dev exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: file="server.js", nodeArgs=["--debug"], ext="js,html", watch=["app/views/**/*.*","gruntfile.js","server.js","config/**/*.js","app/**/*.js"]
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/views/**/*.* gruntfile.js server.js config/**/*.js app/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...OK
+ karma
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build, debug, default, lint, loadConfig, secure, test, test-back, test-front

Running tasks: watch

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.serverViews.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.serverJS.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.clientViews.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.clientJS.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.clientCSS.files exists in config...OK
Live reload server started on port: 35729
Watching app/views/404.server.view.html for changes.
Watching app/views/templates for changes.
Watching app/views/500.server.view.html for changes.
Watching app/views/index.server.view.html for changes.
Watching app/views/layout.server.view.html for changes.
Watching app/views/templates/reset-password-confirm-email.server.view.html for changes.
Watching app/views/templates/reset-password-email.server.view.html for changes.
Watching gruntfile.js for changes.
Watching .git for changes.
Watching app for changes.
Watching config for changes.
Watching node_modules for changes.
Watching public for changes.
Watching server.js for changes.
Watching config/config.js for changes.
Watching config/env for changes.
Watching config/strategies for changes.
Watching config/express.js for changes.
Watching config/init.js for changes.
Watching config/passport.js for changes.
Watching config/env/all.js for changes.
Watching config/env/development.js for changes.
Watching config/env/production.js for changes.
Watching config/env/secure.js for changes.
Watching config/env/test.js for changes.
Watching config/strategies/facebook.js for changes.
Watching config/strategies/github.js for changes.
Watching config/strategies/google.js for changes.
Watching config/strategies/linkedin.js for changes.
Watching config/strategies/local.js for changes.
Watching config/strategies/twitter.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/alerts.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users for changes.
Watching app/controllers/bundles.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/configurations.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/core.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/devices.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/errors.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/invitations.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/orders.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/projects.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/readings.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/services.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users/users.authentication.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users/users.authorization.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users/users.list.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users/users.password.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/controllers/users/users.profile.server.controller.js for changes.
Watching app/models/alert.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/bundle.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/configuration.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/device.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/invitation.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/order.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/project.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/models/reading.server.model.js for changes.
Watching app/tests/order.server.routes.test.js for changes.
Watching app/tests/project.server.model.test.js for changes.
Watching app/tests/project.server.routes.test.js for changes.
Watching app/tests/reading.server.model.test.js for changes.
Watching app/tests/reading.server.routes.test.js for changes.
Watching app/tests/user.server.model.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/views/create-alert.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/views/edit-bundle.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/views/list-bundles.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/views/view-bundle.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/views/create-configuration.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/views/edit-configuration.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/views/list-configurations.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/views/view-configuration.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/admin-panel.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/checkout.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/dashboard.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/details.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/device-config.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/footer.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views/project-panel.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/devices/views/create-device.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/devices/views/edit-device.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/devices/views/list-devices.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/devices/views/view-device.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/views/create-invitation.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/views/edit-invitation.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/views/list-invitations.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/views/view-invitation.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/orders/views/create-order.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/orders/views/edit-order.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/orders/views/list-orders.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/views/authentication/signin.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/views/authentication/signup.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/views/invitation/invitation-invalid.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/views/invitation/invitation-signup.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/views/password/forgot-password.client.view.html for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/alerts.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/services for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/tests for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/views for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/config/alerts.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/controllers/alerts.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/services/alerts.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/alerts/tests/alerts.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/bundles.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/services for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/tests for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/views for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/config/bundles.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/controllers/bundles.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/services/bundles.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/bundles/tests/bundles.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/chart.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/css for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/directives for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/services for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/tests for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/views for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/directives/chart.directive.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/services/d3.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/tests/chart.directive.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/config/configurations.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/configurations.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/services for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/tests for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/views for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/controllers/configurations.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/services/configurations.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/configurations/tests/configurations.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/config/core.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/admin-panel.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/checkout.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/core.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/dashboard.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/device-config.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/header.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/home.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers/project-panel.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/core.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/directives for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/img for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/views for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/directives/chart.directive.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/device.assigner.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/device.encoder.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/device.storage.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/id.encryption.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/menus.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/projects.creator.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/services/projects.storage.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/admin-panel.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/controllerTests for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/directiveTests for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/serviceTests for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/checkout.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/dashboard.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/device-config.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/header.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/home.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/projectpanel.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/tests/serviceTests/project.storage.service.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/controllers/invitations.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/invitations.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/invitations/tests/invitations.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/orders/config/orders.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/orders/controllers/orders.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/config/projects.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/controllers/projects.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/projects.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/controllers for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/services for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/tests for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/views for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/services/projects.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/projects/tests/projects.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/readings/config/readings.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/readings/controllers/readings.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/readings/tests/readings.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/config/users.client.config.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/config/users.client.routes.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/controllers/authentication.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/controllers/invitation-signup.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/controllers/password.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/controllers/settings.client.controller.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/services/authentication.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/services/users.client.service.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/tests/authentication.client.controller.test.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/users.client.module.js for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/config for changes.
Watching public/modules/chart/css/chart.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/admin.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/checkout.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/core.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/dashboard.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/details.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/device-config.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/font-awesome.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/footer.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/header.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/home.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/icomoon.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/overrides.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/core/css/project-panel.css for changes.
Watching public/modules/users/css/users.css for changes.
```

This verbose output stops here, and does nothing after that, no matter what I do in the browser.

The app IS actually running (on localhost:3000) and the livereload and things like that, seem to be working but I see nothing in my terminal output. This is making it really hard to debug and figure out what is being loaded/not being loaded in my app.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

** As a sidenote, I has to reinstall Node and npm recently, not sure if that has anything to do with it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple for me, although why it worked I'm not 100% sure.

Check your package.json :

- look in devDependencies object
- upgrade "grunt-nodemon" version to "~0.4.1" (mine was 0.3.0 previously, I think)
- run npm install

you should now be seeing the correct output!